# Python generator objects: __sizeof__()

Tags: python, generator, internals

This may be a stupid question but I will ask it anyway. I have a generator object:

```
>>> def gen():
...     for i in range(10):
...         yield i
...         
>>> obj=gen()
```

I can measure it's size:

```
>>> obj.__sizeof__()
24
```

It is said that generators get consumed:

```
>>> for i in obj:
...     print i
...     
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
>>> obj.__sizeof__()
24
```

...but `obj.__sizeof__()` remains the same.

With strings it works as I expected:

```
>>> 'longstring'.__sizeof__()
34
>>> 'str'.__sizeof__()
27
```

I would be thankful if someone could enlighten me.

Comment: You might also be interested in [`sys.getsizeof()`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof). It also considers gc overhead (if that matters to you), and it is a little less hackish.

Comment: @mhawke: actually, the OP wasn't even interested in `__sizeof__`! :)

Comment: @NedBatchelder: yes, you're right!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`__sizeof__()` does not do what you think it does. The method returns the internal size in bytes for the given object, not the number of items a generator is going to return.

Python cannot beforehand know the size of a generator. Take for example the following endless generator (example, there are better ways to create a counter):

```
def count():
    count = 0
    while True:
        yield count
        count += 1
```

That generator is endless; there is no size assignable to it. Yet the generator object itself takes memory:

```
>>> count.__sizeof__()
88
```

You don't normally call `__sizeof__()` you leave that to the [`sys.getsizeof()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof), which also adds garbage collector overhead.

If you *know* a generator is going to be finite and you *have* to know how many items it returns, use:

```
sum(1 for item in generator)
```

but note that that *exhausts* the generator.

Comment: Indeed it's possible to have infinite generators or non-deterministic generators

Answer (score 8):

As said in other answers, `__sizeof__` returns a different thing.

Only some iterators have methods that return the number of not returned elements. For example `listiterator` has a corresponding `__length_hint__` method:

```
>>> L = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> it = iter(L)
>>> it
<listiterator object at 0x00E65350>
>>> it.__length_hint__()
5
>>> help(it.__length_hint__)
Help on built-in function __length_hint__:

__length_hint__(...)
    Private method returning an estimate of len(list(it)).

>>> it.next()
1
>>> it.__length_hint__()
4
```

Comment: thanks for the __length_hint__. also len(list(it)) consumes an iterator but __length_hint__ does not.

Comment: @root Yes, `list` consumes it, converts to list (which takes some memory) and only then calculates the length of the created list. While `length_hint` is a specially implemented method just for list iterator object.

Answer (score 1):

`__sizeof__` returns the memory size of an object in bytes, not the length of a generator, which is impossible to determine up front as generators can grow indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that the generator you've created is "finite" (has a countable number of elements) and you don't mind waiting a while you can use the following to get what you want:

```
len(list(gen()))
```

As the other posters said `__sizeof__()` is a measure of how much memory something takes up (a much lower level concept that you probably will rarely need), not its length (which is not a feature of generators since there's no guarantee they have a countable length).