# __sizeof__ str is larger than __sizeof__ a tuple containing that string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, tuples, python-internals

The following code produces the given output.

```
import sys

print('ex1:')
ex1 = 'Hello'
print('\t', ex1.__sizeof__())

print('\nex2:')
ex2 = ('Hello', 53)
print('\t', ex2.__sizeof__())
```

Output:

```
ex1:
     54    
ex2:
     40
```

Why does `__sizeof__()` print a smaller result when a second element is considered? Shouldn't the output be larger? I realize from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477835/python-generator-objects-sizeof) that I should be using `sys.getsizeof()`, but the behavior seems odd nonetheless. I'm using `Python 3.5.2`.

Also, as [@Herbert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4859841/herbert) pointed out, `'Hello'` takes up more memory than `('Hello',)`, which is a `tuple`. Why is this?

Comment: Your first object is not a tuple, it's a string within parenthesis.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is due to the fact that `tuple` objects (and I'm pretty sure all containers except from string) assess their size **not** by including the actual sizes of their respective contents but, rather, by calculating the size of pointers to `PyObject`s times the elements they contain. That is, they hold pointers to the (generic) `PyObject`s contained and that's what contributes to its overall size.

This is hinted in the [Data Model chapter of the Python Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types) manual:

> Some objects contain *references* to other objects; these are called containers. Examples of containers are tuples, lists and dictionaries. The references are part of a container’s value.

<sup>(I'm emphasizing the word references.)</sup>

[In `PyTupleType`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b9a755188ac742029be50ef047ec0969c6d0e921/Objects/tupleobject.c#L791), a struct where the information on the `tuple` type is contained, we see that the [`tp_itemsize`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_itemsize) field has `sizeof(PyObject *)` as its value:

```c
PyTypeObject PyTuple_Type = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyType_Type, 0)
    "tuple",
    sizeof(PyTupleObject) - sizeof(PyObject *),
    sizeof(PyObject *),  // <-- sizeof pointer to PyObject's
```

<sup>`32`bit builds and `64`bit builds of Python have a `sizeof(PyObject *)` equal to 8 bytes.</sup>

This is the value that is going to be multiplied by the number of items contained in the `tuple` instance. When we look at [`object_size`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b9a755188ac742029be50ef047ec0969c6d0e921/Objects/typeobject.c#L4422), the `__sizeof__` method that `tuple`s inherit from `object` (examine `object.__sizeof__ is tuple.__sizeof__`), we see this clearly:

```c
static PyObject *
object_sizeof(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    Py_ssize_t res, isize;

    res = 0;
    isize = self->ob_type->tp_itemsize;
    if (isize > 0)
        res = Py_SIZE(self) * isize;  // <-- num_elements * tp_itemsize
    res += self->ob_type->tp_basicsize;

    return PyLong_FromSsize_t(res);
}
```

see how `isize` (obtained from `tp_itemsize`) is multiplied by [`Py_SIZE(self)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c30098c8c6014f3340a369a31df9c74bdbacc269/Include/object.h#L119), which, is another macro that grabs the `ob_size` value *indicating the number of elements* inside the `tuple`.

This is why, even if we create a somewhat large string inside a tuple instance:

```
t = ("Hello" * 2 ** 10,)
```

with the element inside it having a size of:

```
t[0].__sizeof__()         # 5169
```

the size of the tuple instance:

```
t.__sizeof__()            # 32
```

equals that of one with simply `"Hello"` inside:

```
t2 = ("Hello",)
t[0].__sizeof__()         # 54
t2.__sizeof__()           # 32 Tuple size stays the same.
```

For strings, each individual character increases the value returned from `str.__sizeof__`. This, along with the fact that `tuple`s only store pointers, gives a misleading impression that `"Hello"` has a larger size than the tuple containing it.

Just for completeness, [`unicode__sizeof__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b9a755188ac742029be50ef047ec0969c6d0e921/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L13737) is the one that computes this. It really just multiplies the length of the string with the character size (which depends on what kind the character is `1`, `2` and `4` byte chars).

The only thing I'm not getting with tuples is why it's basic size (indicated by `tb_basicsize`) is listed as `sizeof(PyTupleObject) - sizeof(PyObject *)`. This sheds `8` bytes from the overall size returned; I haven't found any explanation for this (yet).

Comment: Another top answer, but I wonder if the cpython tag is being neglected on these python-internals questions

Comment: I've wondered that myself @Chris_Rands. A while ago, after skimming through the tags top Q's, I've come to realize that most people equate `python-internals` with how `CPython` works, so I'm just rolling with that sentiment :-)