# Python iterator (generator) delete source, still works. what is going on?

Tags: python, generator

I need some clarification on what is going on with the following behavior when using a generator. I'm afraid I am missing something fundamental, so any advice is welcome.

(edit) Specifically my question deals with the `del` of the iterable that an iterator is created on.

My ultimate use case is that I am iterating over a pretty massive corpus for text processing. It isn't so large that it can't be held in memory, but is big enough that training a subsequent model is impossible with it in memory.

So, in my investigation, I attempted the following and I'm confused how this works.

```
>>> iterable = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
>>> iterable.__sizeof__()
    160
>>> iterator = (x+1 for x in iterable)
>>> iterator
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x1019f8570>
>>> iterator.__sizeof__()
64
>>> del iterable
>>> for i in iterator:
...     print(i)
...
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
```

Once I delete the iterable, what is the iterator referencing? How is it still able to have a smaller mem footprint but also succesfully execute (I was under the impression that the generator simply points to existing data, but if it is deleted I have to shrug?)

What am I missing? (something clearly. Sorry. I'm self taught). Thanks in advance!

Comment: `del` doesn't delete things. It unassigns variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python generator objects: \_\_sizeof\_\_()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477835/python-generator-objects-sizeof)

Comment: `del` won't delete the actual memory, just the variable name. So `iterable` will return a `NameError`, but accessing its previous memory will not.

Comment: And that memory stays until say, iterator was del; in which case then and only then the memory would be cleared?

Comment: And? Why does it still work if I assign `iterable = None`

Comment: `iterable` is only a reference to the list object.  The generator comprehension has its own reference to that object that does not rely on `iterable`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd make this a comment, but it needs formatting to be clear:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = [x]
>>> del x
>>> y
[[1, 2, 3]]
```

At heart it's the same thing as your example:  removing the binding for name `x` has no effect at all on the value of `y`, because `y` captured the object `x` *was* bound to at the time `y` was bound.

In the same way, the generator expression you bound to `iterator` captured the then-current binding of `iterable` at the time `iterator` was bound.

However, this isn't entirely straightforward in all cases.  You can [read the PEP that introduced generator expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) for details.  See especially the "Early Binding versus Late Binding" section.

> Only the outermost for-expression is evaluated immediately, the other expressions are deferred until the generator is run

You "got lucky" here (but in a very common way) because `iterable` was in "the outermost for-expression" of your generator expression.  That's why the object `iterable` was bound to was captured *at the time* you created the genexp.

Comment: Ok yup this makes perfect sense. thanks for the answer and the reference